# Sinon: can't mock promise

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, sinon

I know this question is pretty often and I've read all related questions on this but seems like I still can't figure out how to apply them to my case.

This is my error:

```
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I trying to stub a method with next signature:

```
 public async signIn(model: SignInInputModel): Promise<SignInResultModel> {...}
```

And I wan't to stub a response model before unit test starts.
Here is how I trying to do that without any succeess:

```
describe("incorrect behaviour", () => {
        before((done) => {
            sinon.stub(Auth0Service.prototype, "signIn").resolves(() => {
                const result = new SignInResultModel();
                result.success = false;
                result.errorMessage = "foo";
                return result;
            });

            //this not working as well
            //  sinon.stub(Auth0Service.prototype, "signIn").returns(() => {
            //     const result = new SignInResultModel();
            //     result.success = false;
            //     result.errorMessage = "foo";
            //     Promise.resolve(result);
            // });

        });
        it("sinon test", async (done) => {
            request(app)
                .post("/auth/signIn")
                .send()
                .expect(200)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    ...
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
```

What am I do wrong?

Comment: Side note - if you're passing an async function to `before` or `it` you should remove the `done` parameter. The test runner will automatically wait for the promise returned by the passed function before continuing.

Comment: And if you're not returning a promise (like in the "sinon test" above) then you shouldn't be using an async function, since request doesn't return a promise.

Comment: @ChrisTavares yes, this is the right answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just missed to call the `done` function at the end.

The correct answer:

```
sinon.stub(Auth0Service.prototype, "signIn").resolves({
    success: false,
     accessToken: "test",
     errorMessage: "aaa",
     statusCode: 404,
} as SignInResultModel);
 done();
```

Answer (score 0):

`resolves()` should return a value, you're returning a function, which seems wrong.

```
let result = new SignInResultModel();
result.success = false;
result.errorMessage = "foo";
sinon.stub(Auth0Service.prototype, "signIn").resolves(result);
```

Comment: this is a good point, I just figure out that I actually return a function instead of an object but this issue not related to my exception.
I've found that I missed calling `done` function. 
Thanks for your reply!